# Create Composite React Component with Images as background

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a Wrapper component with two images as background and have children layout inside them.

This is in ReactNative but its general React principles.

I can do this with one Image easily,

```
const F = ({children}) => (
  <Image...>{children}</Image>
);
```

but now I want to do this with two images, and say then generalize with n images.

```
const Background = ({children}) => (
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    {image_1}
    {image_2}
  </View>
);
```

And here I am not sure where, or how to place children. I want to avoid anything using `position:absolute`. I've also played with z-index, but I find that that will end up having to involve `position:absolute` as well.

Comment: `position:absolute` could be perfectly fine in your scenario. But what are you trying to achieve? How are the images supposed to be positioned? Next to each other?

Comment: If your images are actually used as layers (i.e. same position on the screen) you will have to go with position:absolute

Comment: @MotiAzu  to make the background be these two images and then add content in front of them. They are not layered images, just one image following another.

Comment: it does seem like I need to go with position:absolute =/

Comment: Don't be sad, position absolute is a friend. He can do things nobody else can.

Comment: @MotiAzu yes, but then I need to deal with relative things and its a hassle to write more code.

Comment: I'll try to help with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want images laid out next to each other as a background, you would need to render a `View` with these images probably using flex. And that `View` will also be position absolutely and stretched all over it's container.
Something along the lines of:

```
const Background = ({children}) => (
  <View style={{position:'absolute', top:0,bottom:0,right:0,left:0, flexDirection: 'column', zIndex: 1}}>
    {children}
  </View>
);

const ContainerOfAllThisStuff = (p) => (
    <View>
        <Background>
            <Image1 />
            <Image2 />
        </Background>
        <RealView />
    </View>
)
```

Basically, `ContainerOfAllThisStuff` will have `Background` no grabbing any space and just stay in it's background because of it's absolute position. And RealView with `flex:1` (and maybe `zIndex`) will grab all the space of the container.